# Executing 2 file with same name

Tags: php, file

I got a strange error happening but not on all server only on a specific server.

I have 2 folders that both contain a file named install.php
for some reasons once i have reach install.php in the first folder with ajax then if i try to run the second install.php file the server deny the request and forbidden the access to that file.

Someone know why ?

thanks

Comment: Any error in the error or access log of the server?

Comment: unfortunately no all i see is in my browser inpector a 403 forbidden

Comment: Directory access configuration and php support configuration of the webserver is correct for the particular folder?

Comment: that is out of my knowledge unfortunately that is why i come here asking :(

Comment: So, can you post relevant parts of webserver's config file? I do not know wchich one you use...

Comment: i will try to do that as soon as i can thanks actually i have to ask my client first.